# error splitting data using the train_test_split from sklearn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, text-classification, naivebayes

not sure how to fix this, please help. below is the code:

```
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
all_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'].values.astype('U'))
vectorizer.vocabulary_
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vectorizer, df['intent'], test_size=0.3, random_state=88)
```

below is the error.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-5cd659a5da4e> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vectorizer, df['intent'], test_size=0.3, random_state=88)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    290     """
    291     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 292     check_consistent_length(*result)
    293     return result
    294 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    250     """
    251 
--> 252     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    253     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    254     if len(uniques) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    250     """
    251 
--> 252     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
    253     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    254     if len(uniques) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _num_samples(x)
    193     if hasattr(x, 'shape') and x.shape is not None:
    194         if len(x.shape) == 0:
--> 195             raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
    196                             " a valid collection." % x)
    197         # Check that shape is returning an integer or default to len

TypeError: Singleton array array(CountVectorizer(stop_words='english'), dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

please help me solve this error. i am following a tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7Yw7VUrMxs). i have tried looking for an error from the above code but i cannot seem to spot one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `all_features` instead of `vectorizer`

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_features, df['intent'], test_size=0.3, random_state=88)
```

Comment: thanks buddy, you are a real life saver. it worked.